# How to upload a photo from mobile phone to Google Forms as an answer?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

One can choose file upload to Google Forms, but when answering in form option only opens Google Drive upload dialog. **Is there any way to upload photo from mobile phone as an answer?** E.g. is it possible to some how add an option to upload photo from mobile with GAS?

I'm building a quick proto to capture some information with photo and form is an excellent option if only user could capture photo while answering the form.

Answer (score 0):

> E.g. is it possible to some how add an option to upload photo from mobile with GAS?

It's not possible to add custom features to the response view of Google Forms.